# SAS PROC SQL TRIM STATEMENT

Tags: sql, sas, trim

I am having problems with a TRIM st

This is the error that I am receiving;

```
ERROR: CLI prepare error: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database]
       Syntax error, expected something like ')' between a string or a Unicode
       character literal and the integer '9'.
```

And this is a sample of the code it is refering to;

```
select trim(a.BR_CBS_CUST(FORMAT "9(4)")) || trim(a.STEM_CBS_CUST(FORMAT "9(6)")) || 
  trim(a.ACTP_CBS_CUST) || trim(a.CDG_CBS_CUST)  (char(20))as CUSTNO
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the full proc sql statement?  This looks like it is using ODBC passthrough but it's not possible to tell from just the snippet you have given us.  THanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider COMPRESS() which can be helpful when removing blanks and concatinating strings.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try LTRIM RTRIM Instead normal Trim?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers. I resolved this in the end as follows: inner join dqviewsp.CBS_PERSONS_XREF as b
/*on a.CustNo=trim(b.BR_CBS_CUST) || trim(b.STEM_CBS_CUST) || trim(b.ACTP_CBS_CUST) || trim(b.CDG_CBS_CUST)*/
on cast(substr(a.custno,1,4) as smallint) = b.br_cbs_cust and
 cast(substr(a.custno,5,6) as integer) = b.stem_cbs_cust and
 cast(substr(a.custno,11,1) as smallint) = b.actp_cbs_cust and
 cast(substr(a.custno,12,1) as smallint) = b.cdg_cbs_cust